# Environmental variables from .env file not available during local migrations in django, heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, migration

I have been developing on Heroku, using the `config` variables to store sensitive and other environmental variables.  While developing locally, I have mirrored these variables in the `.env` file.

What I am finding now is the variables from the `.env` file do not load during migrations.  They ARE loading while running the local web server with `heroku local`, but NOT loading for migrations.  This was not a problem while my local app was still using the default sqlite3 database, because the sqlite default DB was "hard-coded" in the settings file.  However recently I want to use my local Postgresql DB for local dev. OK so I added the `DATABASE_URL` variable to my `.env` file.

I cannot get my local app to migrate to the DB.  I have found out that this is because the `.env` file contents are not added to the `os.environ` mapping duing migrations.

To test, I added a test variable to the `.env` file:

```
TEST="teeeest"
```

Then in `settings.py`:

```
import os
import dj_database_url

if "TEST" not in os.environ:
    raise Exception("No .env vars found.")
```

I tried `python manage.py migrate`:

> File "/Users/apple/heroku/b/b/settings.py", line 16, in 
>       raise Exception("No .env vars found.") Exception: No .env vars found.

However I can run `heroku local` and there is no error.  I have also done further testing to ensure that the `.env` variables ARE available during `heroku local`.

For various reason I want to set my local DB connection string in the `.env` file, but doesn't seem possible at the moment.  Is this the correct behavior for django on heroku?  `.env` file variables are only accessible when you run the server, and not for migrations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out that simply running `python manage.py migrate` did nothing to load the `.env` file variables.  You need to do run the commands in the `heroku local` environment:

```
heroku local:run python manage.py migrate
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-run-a-one-off-command-locally

Comment: and how to load the .env file for windows? when running manage.py makemigrations command?

Answer (score 1):

`manage.py` doesn't know anything about your .env file. You'll need to run the command under something that does; either [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman), which is what Heroku itself uses, or [Honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho), which is a Python implementation.

Comment: I actually just figured it out after a long weekend-> `heroku local:run python manage.py migrate`.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-the-heroku-local-command-line-tool-run-a-one-off-command-locally